# Every net has a universal subnet

Tags: real-analysis

I am having trouble with the following exercise from [tao's blog](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/02/09/245b-notes-10-compactness-in-topological-spaces/)

> **Exercise 23** **(Kelley’s theorem)** Every net ${(x_\alpha)_{\alpha \in A}}$ in a set ${X}$ has a universal subnet ${(x_{\phi(\beta)})_{\beta \in B}}$. (Hint: First use Exercise 5 to find an ultrafilter ${p}$ on ${A}$ that contains the upsets ${\{ \beta \in A: \beta \geq \alpha\}}$ for all ${\alpha \in A}$. Now let ${B}$ be the space of all pairs ${(U,\alpha)}$, where ${\alpha \in U \in p}$, ordered by requiring ${(U,\alpha) \leq (U',\alpha')}$ when ${U \supset U'}$ and ${\alpha \leq \alpha'}$, and let ${\phi: B \rightarrow A}$ be the map ${\phi: (U,\alpha) \mapsto \alpha}$.)

The hint tell me to show $(x_{\phi((U,\alpha)})_{(U,\alpha)\in B}$ is a universal subnet, that is for every $E\subset X$,$(x_{\phi((U,\alpha)})_{(U,\alpha)\in B}$  is in $E$ or $X\setminus E$ for sufficiently large $(U,\alpha)$, I have no idea how to prove this, since the  ultrafilter $p$ is quite unclear for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT Fix $E\subseteq X$. Let $A_E=\{\alpha\in A:x_\alpha\in E\}$; $p$ is an ultrafilter on $A$, so exactly one of the sets $A_E$ and $A\setminus A_E=\{\alpha\in A:\alpha\in X\setminus E\}$ belongs to $p$. There’s no loss of generality in assuming that $A_E\in p$: if not, we just interchange the names of $E$ and $A\setminus E$.

Fix any $\alpha_0\in A_E$, and let $U_0=\{\alpha\in A_E:\alpha_0\le\alpha\}$.

- Explain why $U_0\in p$ (and hence $\langle U_0,\alpha_0\rangle\in B$).
- Verify that $x_{\varphi(\langle U,\alpha\rangle)}=x_\alpha\in E$ whenever $\langle U_0,\alpha_0\rangle\le\langle U,\alpha\rangle\in B$.

Once you’ve done that, you’re almost ready to conclude that

$$\big\langle x_{\varphi(\langle U,\alpha\rangle)}:\langle U,\alpha\rangle\in B\big\rangle$$

is a universal subset of $\langle x_\alpha:\alpha\in A\rangle$.

Comment: Notice that $U_0=A_E\cap \{\alpha:\alpha\geq \alpha_0\}$, since $p$ is a ultrafilter and $A_E,\{\alpha:\alpha\geq\alpha_0\}\in p$, then we have $U_0\in p$.

Comment: @XiangYu: Exactly right. That’s the key point.